# Prove that $(ST)^*=T^*S^*$.

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T:V→V$ and $S:V→W$ are linear operators, then prove that $(ST)^*=T^*S^*$.
I have done in this way that first I show that the domain of the mapping are same i.e. $(ST)^*:W^*→V^*$ and also $T^*S^*:W^*→V^*$.
Now $((ST)^*f)(v)=f(ST(v))$, for $f∈W^*$ and $v∈V$.
And then for other, $(T^*S^*(f))(v)=(T^*(g))(v)=g(Tv) =f(ST(v))$, where $g(v)=f(S(v))$.
I want to clarify my two questions:

$1)$ Is $S:V→W$  mentioned above is a linear operator? As it's domain and codomain vector spaces are different.

$2)$ Is my way to proceed this question is correct?
Please help me if any one can.

Comment: Well, I'd finish off the proof with something like: since we've shown that $((ST)^*f)(v) = (T^*S^*(f))(v)$ for all $v \in V$, that implies that $(ST)^*(f) = T^* S^*(f)$.  And in turn, since that holds for all $f \in W^*$, that implies that $(ST)^* = T^* S^*$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is just fine.

1) It really depends on how you define operator. Some people define operators as just linear maps between vector spaces. Others require the domain and codomain to be the same space.

2) Yes. I would follow Daniel's suggestion or combine the two computations, as I write below.

> Note that for every $f\in W^*$ and $v\in V$, we have
>   \begin{align*}
> (ST)^*(f)(v) = f((ST)v) = f(S(Tv))=(S^*(f))(Tv)=T^*(S^*(f))(v)=(T^*S^*)(f)(v).
> \end{align*}

Comment: Yah I get it. For the first one I was so confused that in my book the definition of linear operator is just like domain and codomain are same but my professor take different. So I was confused.

Answer (score 0):

By definition:
$$(ST)^*\colon W^*\to V^*;f\mapsto fST\tag{1}$$

$S^*\colon W^*\to V^*;f\mapsto fS\tag{2}$

$T^*\colon V^*\to V^*;g\mapsto gT\tag{3}$

So from $(2)$ and $(3)$:

$$T^*S^*\colon W^*\to V^*;f\mapsto fST\tag{4}$$

It follows from $(1)$ and $(4)$ that: $$(ST)^*=T^*S^*$$